# Flutter web app paused after runinig and show web_entrypoint.dart but no any console error

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to run my flutter app in chrome, I was using firebase for sign in and signup and here I got a problem. It is not running in chrome and it showing `web_entrypoint.dart` file and I also tried continuing it but it showing blank in chrome.

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:eorganic/main.dart' as entrypoint;
import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/flutter_web_plugins.dart';
import 'package:eorganic/generated_plugin_registrant.dart';

typedef _UnaryFunction = dynamic Function(List<String> args);
typedef _NullaryFunction = dynamic Function();

Future<void> main() async {
       registerPlugins(webPluginRegistrar);
       await ui.webOnlyInitializePlatform();
       if (entrypoint.main is _UnaryFunction) {
      return (entrypoint.main as _UnaryFunction)(<String>[]);
 }
 return (entrypoint.main as _NullaryFunction)();  
}
```

error: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00SYT.png)